# Извлечь информацию из xml в соответствии с введёнными данными

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть xml:

```xml
<cars>
<car>
<renttarifes>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="0" till="7">2100</tarif>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="7" till="14">1950</tarif>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="14" till="30">1800</tarif>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="30" till="100">1700</tarif>
</renttarifes>
</car>
</cars>
```

Если пользователь вводит, например, 15, то как мне извлечь тариф?

Цифры получаю так:

```
root = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'html.parser')

def get_tarif(car) -> str:
    tarif = car.find_all('tarif')
    return tarif

for car in root.select('car'):
    tarif = get_tarif(car)
    tarif_a = str(tarif)
    tarif_b = re.sub(r'\<.*?\>', '', tarif_a)
```

Здесь я получаю только стоимость, а вот как извлечь тариф в соответствии с введённым количеством дней?

Comment: При 15 нужно вывести 1800?

Comment: @gil9red, да. Уже вижу ответ. Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<cars>
<car>
<renttarifes>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="0" till="7">2100</tarif>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="7" till="14">1950</tarif>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="14" till="30">1800</tarif>
<tarif uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b" bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="30" till="100">1700</tarif>
</renttarifes>
</car>
</cars>
'''

root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

days = 15
for tarif in root.select('tarif'):
    start = int(tarif['from'])
    end = int(tarif['till'])
    if days in range(start, end + 1):
        print(tarif.text)
        print(tarif)
        break

# 1800
# <tarif bounty="100" dim="сутки" from="14" till="30" uid="485916e2-f66e-11ea-aa7e-000c29a3594b">1800</tarif>
```